# How to use PureRenderMixin (React js) in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, npm, mixins

I am building an app with Meteor 1.2 and react, and the react-meteor-data mixin to get the data from my publish methods.
I think a good idea is to have an "AppWrapper" component with all the state and data subscriptions, that passes via props to the "App" component, who will render all the components down to the hierarchy...
Although this is working, I would like to have all the render components pure and with immutable data.
What is the way to proceed?

1) There is already the addon in the react package but I don't know how to use it?

2) I should install it from npm and wait for Meteor 1.3 package system?

3) Is it possible to implement a custom shouldComponentUpdate with some immutable library?

I will appreciate any ideas or experience in this topic, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Go to point 3

2) Go to point 3

3) Of course! As an example: [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

```
const AppWrapper = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ReactMeteor.Mixin],

    getMeteorState () {
        return {
            data: Immutable.Map({
                userId: Meteor.userId()
            })
        };
    },

    shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
        return !this.state.data.equals(nextState.data);
    },

    render () {
        return (
            <App data={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
});

// This is basic example with pure component.
// Of course this might be another component created with 
// React.createClass implementing it's own shouldComponentUpdate method.
const App = ({ data }) => (
    <p>Your userId: {data.get('userId')}</p>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this way, only 3 more questions: 1) Can I remove the react-meteor-data package because I assume its not longer necessary? 2) Can I implement shouldComponentUpdate only in AppWrapper component, and be confident all children will update only when needed? 3) I know I asked if this scenario is possible but I also assume this as a good practice, right?

Comment: 1) This package is just a *helper* to integrate React with Meteor. You can still use it, find your own way to fetch your data or use a different package (for example https://github.com/vazco/meteor-universe-utilities-react).

Comment: 2) shouldComponentUpdate checks only component, which implements it. If your AppWrapper *should update*, but it children does not - it can implement this method too, and prevent unnecessary render.

Comment: 3) shouldComponentUpdate is a way of optimization (preventing unnecessary rendering), so yeah - it's a good practice, but remember: **Premature optimization is the root of all evil**.

Comment: 1) Ok, 2) If I pass only necessary subset of props to children  and so on, so the last leave only receives, say one property called message_id, then if the Wrapper should update, but message_id have not changed, then I assume React and Immutable do this job for me? (Not update the component because the property hasnt changed), 3) Ok, I always like to start things thinkin in performance, but I see the point, thanks!

Comment: React will omit only redundancy in DOM updates, not in your component logic, so if component will only render it data - yes, it will do it for you, but if component receiving id will - for example - subscribe document with that id - you should check if id has changed.

Comment: Ok, in my case only AppWrapper will subscribe to data sources and manage whole app state, so every other component only will receive props, so I will check no neccesary updates should be made ( shouldComponentUpdate() { console.log('this should no be right') }...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102163/discussion-between-radoslaw-m-and-jose-manuel-aguirre).